# scp protocol error: bad mode

Tags: ssh, scp

when I try a scp transfer I get this error:

```
protocol error: bad mode
```

PD: I can establish a ssh connection.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you do `scp -1` or `scp -2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem was a personalized welcome message of bash

Comment: So what's the solution? If you can't change the welcome message, is there a way to still scp?

Comment: @apdnu run it on interactive shell only: https://serverfault.com/a/146747/84279 - I had the same issue, broke a lot of things, mainly SCP - since added the `if` it works just fine.

Answer (score 8):

So, this is a bit of question necromancy, but since I got here, and then realised what the answer was after reading the first answer, I figured I'd put this here for other wayward souls.

Because of the way scp works (over stdin/stdout over ssh AFAIK), having a naive bashrc that prints messages breaks the formatting scp is expecting, and thus the connection.

As suggested in various answers elsewhere (linked below), modifying your dot-files is usually the way to fix this:

- [You can check in the relevant file (usually .bashrc) whether the shell is interactive before printing messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12442753/180184),
- Or, slightly less directly, [check whether PS1 is blank](https://superuser.com/questions/690735/can-i-tell-if-im-in-an-scp-session-in-my-bashrc) (which it should be in a noninteractive session unless something has altered it).

Answer (score 1):

Check the content of your .bashrc and .bash_login files. Make sure there's nothing that sends output to the tty.

In my case, I was running a command in my .bashrc to tell me what version of Linux I had. When I deleted that, everything worked fine.