# Can I tell if I'm in an scp session in my .bashrc?

Tags: bash, unix, scp, bashrc

Inside my `.bashrc`, I'm doing a bunch of magic that causes problems when I'm trying to do an `scp`. The solution I've been going with is to manually ssh to the target machine, disable my `.bashrc`, do the copy, and then re-enable my `.bashrc`. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Which OS? The answer depends on whether you are on Mac OS or any other *Nix

Comment: This screams of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). Please show us your `.bashrc`, explain what you are trying to do, and explain what problems you get. Also tell us the OSes on all machines involved. Especially if any of the are OSX since they have decided to make teh default shell a login shell so `.bashrc` is ignored.

Comment: What's happening in the `.bashrc` is largely irrelevant here. The point was that I just wanted to skip most of it if I was in `scp` instead of `ssh`, but I forgot about the non-interactive shell trick that Tourniquet pointed out in the accepted answer. That solved the issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My standard bashrc on debian had this as the first lines:

```
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi
```

This checks if the variable $PS1 is set (which only is set if you're on an interactive shell), and prevents the execution of the rest if it isn't.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for.